# Clicking on a delete icon in a html page is scrolling to the top of the page - Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am a novice at knockout.js. I have a code which I am trying to debug. The issue I am facing in very new to me. A delete button is placed in a div and the purpose of it is to delete the respective section. I am observing a strange thing. If the page is at 100% zoom and if the page has 10 sections. Say 3 sections are visible and 7 sections are not. the section which is hidden from the user view is not getting deleted upon click of the delete button. Instead, on click of the delete button in these 7 sections, the focus reaches to the top of the page.

If I decrease the zoom to say 60%, 7 sections are visible on the page and 3 are hidden. Now I am able to delete 7 sections without any issue. But delete is not working on the 3 which are not visible to the user. As soon as I delete a couple of section from the top, then when the last 3 sections are visible to the user, then the user is able to delete these sections too. I don't understand what could be the issue. The below code has only on one such block.

[image]

```
<div class="well border-editable field-container" data-bind="foreach: fields">
<!-- ko if: !$parent.isApproved && !$parents[1].isCloned -->
    <div class="hover-icon field" data-bind="drag: $parent.reorderField">
        <div class="well well-xs border-bar field-body clearfix" data-bind="event: {mouseleave: closeTooltip}">
            <div class="field-operation" data-bind="visible: id != $parent.editingField().id">
                <span class="field-operation-item">
                    <!-- ko if: $parents[1].status != 'distributed' -->
                    <!-- ko if: type() != 'outcome' && type() != 'cm' && type() != 'am' && type() != 'al'-->
                    <a href="#" class="tooltip_trigger" data-bind="sure: $parent.removeField, btnText: 'Delete', tipText: 'Are you sure?'" data-placement="top" title="Delete" tabindex="0">
                        <i class="icon icon-trash-empty"></i>
                    </a>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko if: (type() == 'outcome' && !$parents[1].cmField()) || 
                                (type() == 'cm' && !$parents[1].amField()) || 
                                (type() == 'am' && !$parents[1].afField()) ||
                                (type() == 'al' && !$parents[1].alfField()) --><!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko if: type() == 'outcome' && $parents[1].cmField() --><!-- /ko -->    
                    <!-- ko if: type() == 'cm' && $parents[1].amField() --><!-- /ko -->    
                    <!-- ko if: type() == 'am' && $parents[1].afField()  --><!-- /ko -->  
                    <!-- ko if: type() == 'al' && $parents[1].alfField()  --><!-- /ko --> 
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko if: $parents[1].status == 'distributed' --><!-- /ko -->
                </span>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="template: { name: 'field-' + type(), data: $data }">
                <!-- ko if: id !== $parents[1].editingField().id -->
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="text-primary" data-bind="text: label">Number</label>
                            <p class="help-block" data-bind="text: description"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="fake-text" data-bind="text: value"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: id === $parents[1].editingField().id --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: $parent.isApproved || $parents[1].isCloned --><!-- /ko -->
```

Here is the javascript code: ( Let me know if you need any other info )

```
    function removeField () {
        var activeSection = _getActiveSection();
        activeSection.removeField(removeFieldModel);
    }
    function _getActiveSection () {
        var activeSectionId = self.activeSectionId();
        var sections = self.displaySections();
        return  _.find(sections, function (section) {
            return section.id == activeSectionId;
        }) || sections[0] || {};
    }
    self.displaySections = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return _.union(ko.unwrap(self.linkedSections), ko.unwrap(self.sections));
    });
```

I am not sure what extra code would be needed for you guys to help me debug this. Let me know if you need any other information.

Here is a video demo of what I am trying to explain.
[VIDEO DEMO LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15_ZUFJ2waBqsvL-TEc0geaNvXMgk5Mi6/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks.

Comment: Need the JS code, to see the functions that do the delete operation

Comment: Seems like some "lazy rendering" going on. The fields that are not visible to the user are not even loaded - no way to remove something that's not loaded. But, how are you deleting something that's not even visible?

Comment: @ArnabBhagabati, what is Lazy rendering? As you can see in the video, doesn't look like lazy rendering. Only that it is not in the visible area of the page.

Comment: Showing some of your Javascript would be helpful. At least the `removeField` function, and the `sure` custom binding.

Comment: Based on your video, to me at first glance it seems like this might have nothing to do with knockout, but with the tooltip library which you're using. I guess this because the tooltip doesn't show up so you don't even have a chance to trigger the bound knockout action. The issue might be in the `sure` custom binding. When the page scrolls to the top, it most of the times indicates a link click with a pure `#` in it. Probably the tooltip doesn't get set up for the problematic elements.

Comment: Still need to see your custom binding code...

Answer (score 4):

Clicking an `<a>` anchor tag with the `href` set to `#` will scroll a page to the top unless you're calling the [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method on the click event in your JavaScript.

The simplest way to fix this may just be to remove `href="#"` from the element, as it's functionally unnecessary.

Comment: Don't know why this is downvoted. This is definitely the direct cause of the issue. The root cause might be that the tooltip library is not set up for the problematic elements. The issue might be in the library itself or in the `sure` custom binding.

Comment: From the video it does look like it have an herf="#" attribute assigned to that delete button.

Comment: Adding to this, an `<a>` tag without an `href` is functionally the same as a button - but semantically incorrect (and not inclusive to screen-reader users). Consider replacing the `<a>` tag with a `<button>` tag.